# in NFA is every state itself contained in set generated by transition function when considering epsilon transition from that state?

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

in $\epsilon$-NFA (NFAs involving $\epsilon$ transitions) when we have $\epsilon$ transitions, I understand it as where can we go if we don't read any symbol from the input tape, then I think every state $q$ from which we are considering transition must belong to $\delta(q,\epsilon)$ because if we don't read anything, we can of course stay in the state where we are at now, I am asking whether $\epsilon$ transition from state to itself is assumed? for example, if we have some state $q_i$ which has $\epsilon$ transition to state $q_j$  then is $\delta(q_i, \epsilon)$=$\{q_j, q_i\}$ or just $\{q_j\}$, I think it's just matter of convention and wouldn't make significant difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make this a bit formal and let's do the following exercise:
For a given NFA, $M = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$, let us construct another NFA $M' = (Q, \Sigma, \delta', q_0, F)$ where $\delta'$ is the same as $\delta$ with additional $\epsilon$-transition self-loop on every state. We would like to prove these two machines are equivalent, that is, $L(M) = L(M')$.

Proof for $L(M) \subseteq L(M')$:
For every string $w \in L(M) \subseteq \Sigma^*$, there is a transition path in $M$ from $q_0$ to some final state $q \in F$. By construction the same path also exist in $M'$ thus $w \in L(M')$.

Proof for $L(M') \subseteq L(M)$:
For every string $w \in L(M') \subseteq \Sigma^*$, there is a transition path in $M'$ from $q_0$ to some final state $q \in F$. Now, due to our additional $\epsilon$-transition self-loops, this path may contain runs (consecutive repetitions) of the same states. Now if we collapse each run into just a single state, it will give us a trace on $M$ from $q_0$ to the same final state $q \in F$. Thus, $w \in L(M)$.

Comment: thank you, this proves in fact that it doesn't matter which idea we choose, both describe the same language.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on what you mean by $\delta(q,\epsilon)$.

First possibility is that $\delta$ specifies the transitions (the arrows in the state diagram). In that case we have $\delta(q_i,\epsilon) =\{q_j\}$ to indicate the single edge.

The other possibility is that $\delta$ specifies computations, sometimes called the extended transition function: $q\in \delta(p,w)$ iff there is a computation on the input word $w$ starting in state $p$ and ending in state $q$. In that case $\delta(q_i,\epsilon) =\{q_i,q_j\}$ is what we need.

Comment: thank you for the answer. computation vs transition perspective is interesting, fact that both idea describe the same language is shown in the answer above, so I accept the above answer, however this idea is interesting as well. so I upvote it as well, thank you!